Should you mark finished SFMC journeys as 'Stopped'?
It's a pretty basic question. I'm trying to put together a 'recommendations' paper for an organisation. To understand their journeys, the first thing I did was download the list of all the 'running' journeys. To my surprise, they had 700 'running' journeys.
When I dug deeper, I found out that they use 'single send journeys' for newsletters too - which is okay. But they don't mark it as 'stopped'.
I personally think that it's best practice to mark your journeys as stopped once completed for BAU/Email hygiene purposes. I'd love to get some thoughts on this. Should it be marked as stopped once done or leave it as running? I'd like to hear more strategic views

there is no system benefit marking them as stop

technically, does not matter; process-wise, dependency control / regressions is a thing though. Let's say you change the template and it's used by journey emails, what journeys need an update? Obviously 700 / 70 / 7 updates do make some kind of difference. I understand that one-off journeys don't care, but sifting through all of that alone is already an interesting job - enough of this sort of stuff, and at some point you gotta hire and pay folks to give recommendations :)

Thank you, that's a great point Jonas
